# Properly running code in android main thread

Tags: android

So started programming android apps, mostly open source and tutorials to learn the language.

I have a problem now where if a user has signed in once, that he never has to sign in again. I used SharedPref for this after reading alot of answers on here, but the app is jumping frames due to this..

heres my code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Login.this);
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
String remUsername = prefs.getString("username", null);
String remPassword = prefs.getString("password", null);

if (remUsername != null && remPassword != null)
{
    String result = null;

    try {
        result = imService.authenticateUser(
        remUsername.toString(),
        remPassword.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, FriendList.class);
    startActivity(i);
    Login.this.finish();
}
```

Comment: I suppose your `authenticateUser()` method performs an HTTP request? If so, you must perform it in a separate thread, otherwise you will face jumping frames and even ANRs. Read this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Yes it does an HTTP request. I have read that it's not supposed to be in the main thread but I have no idea where else to do it, if I put it anywhere else the use doesn't get authenticated and needs re-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jumping frames are probably due to a resource-intensive operation (such as an HTTP request) being executed by the main thread. You must perform such operations in a separate thread, while leaving only UI and non-intensive operations for the main thread (that's why it is called the "UI" thread).

Read the basics [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html). Then you can implement it using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), for example. However for simplicity it is suggested to use a specialized library such as [Volley](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) or [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).